# Docker private registries and the default installer

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, upstart, docker-registry

I am trying to set up a private Docker registry. I [found this tutorial](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/deploying.md
) which states I need to run:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

But this implies that Docker is already installed & running on the server.  So I created a new Ubuntu 14.04 (`upstart`-based) VM and installed Docker [using the recommended procedure](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installation
) and verified that Docker is running by using `docker -v`.

A few concerns/issues here:

#### If Docker is already installed as an upstart service/daemon, how do I configure it to run using the “Registry Mode” command?

I need Docker to run using the registry command shown above, **but it’s already running on the VM.** How do I get modify the service/daemon to run the registry command, do I need to configure `upstart`?

#### Where can I find docs on the arguments passed into this registry command?

I can’t find any docs on what these various command-line args are. `5000:5000`…what does that do?!? `--restart=always`? Any links/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Docker Registry* is just another container that runs on your *Docker Host*.

The `--restart=always` will set the container to restart if it goes down. (Like after a system reboot)

The `5000:5000` is the published port mapping for the container, Docker Registry will listen on port 5000.

Good documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/docker/distribution)

Comment: Thanks @Michael (+1) - can you confirm that [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) is the official registry container? Thanks again!

Comment: Just be sure to pull registry:2 as the other version is deprecated.